# Can not deserialize instance of Object out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, jackson, json, object-object-mapping

I have two object one is Dashboard and second is Room i  have a json which is look like this

```
  {
"hotel_id":"1",
"hotel_room":"200",
"hotel_properties":[{
        "id":"1",
        "room_type":"Single",
        "rack_rate":"2000",
        "publish_rate":"1800",
        "discount":"10",
        "availiable":"40",
        "total":"50"
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "room_type":"Double",
        "rack_rate":"4000",
        "publish_rate":"3600",
        "discount":"10",
        "availiable":"45",
        "total":"50"
      }
      ] 
  }
```

And the Object is

```
public class DashBoard {
    private int hotel_id;
    private int hotel_room;
    @JsonProperty("hotel_properties")
    private Room hotel_properties;
    }
```

There is another Object Room which is look like this

```
public class Room { 
    private Long id;
    private String room_type;
    private String rack_rate;
    private String publish_rate;
    private String discount;
    private String availiable;
    private String total;
}
```

I am Hide all constructor,setter and getter for Stackoverflow but it is in my code
i want parse Json to Object using ObjectMapper from an URL using this code

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            JSONObject json =  jsonReader.readJsonFromUrl("http://localhost/quinchy/json/dashboard.json");
            DashBoard dsh = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), DashBoard.class); 
            System.out.println(json.toString());
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i get this error

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of Object out of START_ARRAY token
```

please help me out from this

Comment: use `List<Room>`  instead of `Room` in `DashBoard` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `JSON` String you posted, it looks like there is a list of `Room` objects. But you have used a single object.

In your `DashBoard` class, try changing:

```
private Room hotel_properties;
```

to:

```
private List<Room> hotel_properties;
```